# What is the definition of "a derivation of a sequent "?

Tags: logic, computer-science, proof-theory, natural-deduction, sequent-calculus

In Chapter IV.  A Sequent Calculus in Ebbinghaus' Mathematical Logic, [a sequent is defined as](https://books.google.com/books?id=4sbSBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA60&ots=VAFMA45zir&dq=If%20we%20call%20a%20nonempty%20list%20(sequence)%20of%20formulas%20a%20sequent%2C%20then%20we%20can%20use%20sequents%20to%20describe%20%22stages%20in%20a%20proof%22.&pg=PA60#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> If we call a nonempty  list (sequence) of formulas **a sequent**, then we can use sequents to describe "stages in a proof". For instance, the "stage"  with assumptions $\phi_1,\dots,\phi_n$
> and claim $\phi$  is rendered by the sequent $\phi_1\dots \phi_n \phi$.  The sequence $\phi_1 \dots\phi_n$ is  called  the  antecedent  and  $\phi$   the  succedent of the  sequent  $\phi_1\dots \phi_n \phi$.

and [a sequent is defined to be derivable](https://books.google.com/books?id=4sbSBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA60&ots=VAFMA45zir&dq=If%20we%20call%20a%20nonempty%20list%20(sequence)%20of%20formulas%20a%20sequent%2C%20then%20we%20can%20use%20sequents%20to%20describe%20%22stages%20in%20a%20proof%22.&pg=PA61#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> If, in the calculus $\mathfrak{S}$, there is a derivation of the sequent $\Gamma \phi$, then we write
> $\vdash \Gamma \phi$ and say that $\Gamma \phi$ is  **derivable**.
>
> **1.1 Definition.**  A formula $\phi$ is formally provable or derivable from a set $\Phi$
> of formulas  (written: $\Phi \vdash \phi$)  if and only if there are finitely many formulas
> $\phi_1,\dots,\phi_n$  in $\Phi$ such that $\vdash \phi_1 \dots\phi_n \phi$

**Question**: What is the definition of "a derivation of the sequent $\Gamma \phi$"? (Has it been defined in the book?)

Is "a derivation of the sequent $\Gamma \phi$" defined as a sequence of sequents, where

- the first sequent can be derived from an  inference rule which has no sequent in their assumption parts, and
- each following sequent follows from some previous sequents by some inference rule?

Thanks.

---

[The book gives rules of inference](https://books.google.com/books?id=4sbSBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA60&ots=VAFMA45zir&dq=If%20we%20call%20a%20nonempty%20list%20(sequence)%20of%20formulas%20a%20sequent%2C%20then%20we%20can%20use%20sequents%20to%20describe%20%22stages%20in%20a%20proof%22.&pg=PA62#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> We divide **the rules of the sequent calculus** $\mathfrak{S}$ into the following categories:
> structural  rules  (2.1,  2.2),  connective  rules  (2.3,  2.4,  2.5,  2.6),  quantifier
> rules (4.1,4.2) and equality rules (4.3,4.4).

All the inference rules have the form of

$$ \frac{sequent}{sequent} $$

except two inference rules which have no sequent in their assumption parts:

> [2.2 Assumption Rule (Assm).](https://books.google.com/books?id=4sbSBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA60&ots=VAFMA45zir&dq=If%20we%20call%20a%20nonempty%20list%20(sequence)%20of%20formulas%20a%20sequent%2C%20then%20we%20can%20use%20sequents%20to%20describe%20%22stages%20in%20a%20proof%22.&pg=PA62#v=onepage&q&f=false)
>
> $$ \frac{}{\Gamma \phi} $$
>
> if $\phi$  is a member of $\Gamma$.

and

> [4.3 Reflexivity Rule for Equality (==)](https://books.google.com/books?id=4sbSBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA60&ots=VAFMA45zir&dq=If%20we%20call%20a%20nonempty%20list%20(sequence)%20of%20formulas%20a%20sequent%2C%20then%20we%20can%20use%20sequents%20to%20describe%20%22stages%20in%20a%20proof%22.&pg=PA67#v=onepage&q&f=false).
>
> $$ \frac{}{t==t} $$

Answer (score 3):

It seems that an explicit definition of "derivation" is lacking.

The first occurrence of the term is at page 16, in the context of the [*calculus of terms*](https://books.google.it/books?id=4sbSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA15).

The calculus is a set of *rules* to generate *terms*.

The process to produce terms is described:

> We say that one can *derive* the string $s$ in the calculus of terms. The *derivation* just described can be given schematically as follows: [a sequence of terms with the corresponding rule].

The same for *formulas* [page 17].

Thus, a *derivation* in the *calculus of sequents* is a sequence of *sequents* ["we use sequents to describe "stages in a proof" ", [page 60](https://books.google.it/books?id=4sbSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA60)], where each sequent is produced from the previous ones according to the rules of the calculus.

This is the usual notion of [derivation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formal_Logic/Sentential_Logic/Derivations) in a formal system: the only difference is that the "building block" is not a single *formula* but a *sequent*.

Comment: When viewing a derivation as a sequence of sequents,  must the first sequent in the sequence be derived from an inference rule which has no sequent in its assumption part?

Comment: @Tim - Yes; see 2.2 Assumption rule: a sequent $\Gamma \varphi$ where $\varphi$ is a member of $\Gamma$ is the "starting" axiom. In standard Sequent calculus, axioms are $A \vdash A$.