# Sequent calculi: Formalizing the term "derivation"

Tags: logic, reference-request, soft-question, proof-theory

**1. Context**
Currently, I am writing a text that involves a certain sequent calculus, call it $S$. I want to define a function on the set $P_S$ of all derivations in $S$ by well-founded recursion on the partial order on $P_S$ given by the subproof-relation.

The meaning of the expression "derivation in a sequent calculus" probably is obvious to the working logician. That might be one reason why the introductory texts on proof theory that I have read (e.g. Troelstra, Ebbinghaus, Negri) do not formalize the terms "derivation in a sequent calculus“ or "proof in a sequent calculus“. However, without a formalization my attempts to define the subproof-relation etc. are unsatisfactory. Defining the set of derivations inductively seems like a good idea.

**2.Questions**
What are common ways to formalize the term "derivation in a sequent calculus“ in the literature? (Please give references.)
As a finite list as suggested in the question posed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3767294/what-is-the-definition-of-a-derivation-of-a-sequent)? As a graph (i.e. a proof tree)? Or simply without specifying "what" object a proof is: "(*insert initial sequent here*) is a proof. If $\nu$ is a proof, then (*insert inference rule application in sequent calculus notation*) is a proof“?
What formalization do you prefer, and why?

EDIT: I believe that this question is not a duplicate of the one referenced above. The referenced question asks, whether a specific text (Ebbinghaus) gives a definition of the term derivation — to which the answer is apparently "not explicitly".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the definition of "a derivation of a sequent "?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3767294/what-is-the-definition-of-a-derivation-of-a-sequent) If not, please edit your question to make it more precise.

Comment: See [Takeuti](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Proof_Theory/Idl6K-W69NYC), page 11: a *formal proof* (or **LK**-proof) is a tree of sequents satisfying the following condition: (1) the topmost sequents are initial sequents; (2) every sequent except the lowest one is an upper sequent of an inference whose lower sequent is also in the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See also Andrzej Indrzejczak, [Sequents and Trees: An Introduction to the Theory and Applications of Propositional Sequent Calculi (2021, Springer)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Sequents_and_Trees/GKgPEAAAQBAJ), page 11:

> Proofs in Sequent Calculi (SC) are usually built as trees of sequents (i.e. with nodes labelled with sequents) with axioms as leaves and the proven sequent as a root. Formally this notion may be defined inductively as follows:

> 1. An axiomatic sequent $S$ is a proof of a sequent $S$.

> 2. If $\mathcal D$ is a proof of a sequent $S$, then $\dfrac {\mathcal D}{S'}$ is a proof of a sequent $S'$, provided that $S$ is an instance of the premiss and $S'$ an instance of the conclusion of some one-premiss rule.

> 3. [The same for two-premises rules.]

In a nutshell, the definition is the same as that of Natural Deduction: the only difference is that the nodes of the tree are *sequents* instead of *formulas*.